# MEAN RESTful application error handling server crashes

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I've just followed a tutorial for creating a simple RESTful api using the MEAN stack from the heroku webpage. What I did was just cloning the repo that contains the sample code, added my mongodb_uri from mLab and then run the app locally (npm start).

It works perfectly, but when I try to make an invalid entry (not providing name and last name to a contact) the express server crashes and the entry is made on my database (which is inconsistent).

I've opened an issue on the github repo but I got no answers, I think that there must be something wrong with the error handling but I don't know what it might be.

Here it is what I get when the server crashes:

```
ERROR: Invalid user input
/Users/nanop/Desktop/mean-contactlist/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/nanop/Desktop/mean-contactlist/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:719:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/nanop/Desktop/mean-contactlist/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:164:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/nanop/Desktop/mean-contactlist/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:250:15)
    at /Users/nanop/Desktop/mean-contactlist/server.js:72:23
    at /Users/nanop/Desktop/mean-contactlist/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:421:18
    at handleCallback (/Users/nanop/Desktop/mean-contactlist/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
    at /Users/nanop/Desktop/mean-contactlist/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:726:5
    at /Users/nanop/Desktop/mean-contactlist/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:428:18
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:433:9)
```

And finally this is the handleError method defined which I think it's ok:

```
function handleError(res, reason, message, code) {
  console.log("ERROR: " + reason);
  res.status(code || 500).json({"error": message});
}
```

This is the repo I refer to: https://github.com/chrisckchang/mean-contactlist